# Get all previous values for every row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm about to write a backtesting tool and so for every row I'd like to have access to all the dataframe till the given row. In the following example I'm doing it from a fixed index using a loop. I'm wondering if there is any better solution.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
N
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":np.arange(N)})
for i in range(3,N):
    print(df["a"][:i].values)
```

**UPDATE (toy example)**
I need to apply a custom function to all the previous values. Here as a **toy** example I will use the sum of the square of all previous values.

```
def toyFun(v):
    return np.sum(v**2)

res = np.empty(N)
res[:] = np.nan
for i in range(3, N):
    res[i] = toyFun(df["a"][:i].values)

df["res"] = res
```

Comment: What is the output that you want?

Comment: Why do you want access to everything? Would a cumulative sum suffice?

Comment: I don't need a cumulative sum. I need to apply a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are indexing rows for a particular column say 'a', you can use `.iloc` indexer (i stands for index, loc means location) to index on the columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4]})
print(df.a.iloc[:2]) # get first two values
```

So, you can do:

```
for i in range(3, 10):
    print(df.a.iloc[:i])
```

Comment: The problem is not how to access the data but how to do it recursively without using a loop.

Comment: That's confusing now. You mentioned 'for every row'. What's the expected output?

Comment: Sorry for it. I need to work,in any row, with all previous values. So in row 3 i'd like to have the dataframe till that point, and so on for the following rows. I can accomplish this using a loop but i'd like to know if i can avoid it.

Comment: @user32185 could you post in your question an example of input and output? :)

Comment: Done. Please take the function just as example.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use a temporary column with the direct results, that way you are not re-calculating everything.

df["a"].apply(lambda x: x**2).cumsum()

Then re-index as you which:
res[3:] = df["a"].apply(lambda x: x**2).cumsum()[2:N-1].values

or directly to the dataframe.

Comment: that is a toy function. I want to use a different one.
If I really wanted to calculate that I could just use  `df["res"] = np.cumsum(df["a"]**2).shift(1)` and `df["res"][:3] = np.nan`

Comment: then, maybe: df[['a']].apply(lambda x: toyFun(df[['a']][:x.name].values), axis=1) and re-index.